# Color Tracking Drone Code Test

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to follow a GitHub to allow my AR Drone to fly autonomously for some time; however, I am having a lot of troubles setting up.

As a follow up to my prior question, I was able to solve

```
import cv2
import libardrone.libardrone
```

I reinstalled opencv and I realized the documentation was incorrect; it was supposed to be

```
import libardrone.ardrone
```

Solving these two problems let me to be able to attempt the track.py given here: https://github.com/JJLewis/ColorTracking-ARDrone2.0-Python.

Running track.py gives me the follow errors even though I have ffmpeg installed correctly.

```
WARNING:root:Connection to ardrone

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/track.py", line 180, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/track.py", line 19, in main
    drone = libardrone.ARDrone(True, False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/ardrone.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.network_process = arnetwork.ARDroneNetworkProcess(com_pipe_other, is_ar_drone_2, self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/arnetwork.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.ar2video = ar2video.ARVideo2(self._drone, drone.debug)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/ar2video.py", line 37, in __init__
    h264 = h264decoder.H264Decoder(self, drone.image_shape)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/h264decoder.py", line 82, in __init__
    raise Exception("You need to install ffmpeg to be able to run ardrone")
Exception: You need to install ffmpeg to be able to run ardrone
>>> Exception in thread Thread-35:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/arnetwork.py", line 86, in run
    video_socket, nav_socket, control_socket = _connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libardrone/arnetwork.py", line 75, in _connect
    control_socket.connect(('192.168.1.1', ARDRONE_CONTROL_PORT))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Entering FFMPEG into my Mac terminal yields the following: which leads me to believe that FFMPEG is installed correctly; however it is not detected or something.

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-vda
```

Doing brew info opencv shows a check for FFMPEG for openCV so I am not really sure how I am getting an error for this part of the code.
As a beginner, I am having difficulties resolving these issues. My specifications are as follows Mac 10.12, Python 2.7.14, and OpenCV 3.3.0_3.

Comment: That looks like just homebrew ffmpeg.  Can you verify that you also installed Python bindings for it?

Comment: I did pip install ffmpeg-python